# How to convert a WPF Button.Click Event into Observable using Rx and F#

Tags: wpf, f#, system.reactive, routedevent

I am trying to replicate some C# code which creates an `IObservable` from a `Button.Click` event.
I want to port this code to F#.

Here is the original C# code which compiles without errors:

```
Observable.FromEvent<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
                                    h => new RoutedEventHandler(h),
                                    h => btn.Click += h,
                                    h => btn.Click -= h))
```

Here is my failing attempt to do the same in F#:

```
Observable.FromEvent<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
            Func<EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>, RoutedEventHandler>(fun h -> RoutedEventHandler(h)),
            Action<RoutedEventHandler>(fun h -> btn.Click.AddHandler h),
            Action<RoutedEventHandler>(fun h -> btn.Click.RemoveHandler h))
```

Everything is happy except for the second line of the statement.

The F# compiler complains about `fun h -> RoutedEventHandler(h)` because
it doesn't want to except `h` as a parameter to the `RoutedEventHandler` constructor.

On th other hand the C# compiler seems to have no problem accepting `h => new RoutedEventHandler(h)`

Interestingly enough, in both code samples (C# and F#) the type of `h` is `EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>`.

The error message I am getting from the F# compiler is:

> Error 2   This expression was expected to have type     obj -> RoutedEventArgs -> unit     but here has type     EventHandler

The signature for `RoutedEventHandler` that I found inside PresentationCore is:

`public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);`

As you can see it does take an `object` and `RoutedEventArgs` as parameters, so the F# compiler is actually correct.

Is there some magic that the C# compiler does behind the scenes to make this work that the F# compiler doesn't or am I just missing something here?

Either way, how can I make this work in F#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to make an `IObservable<_>` out of a WPF Button.Click event is to cast it:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Controls

let btn = new Button()
let obsClick = btn.Click :> IObservable<_>
```

Examining obsClick...

```
val obsClick : IObservable<Windows.RoutedEventArgs>
```

This is possible because the F# representation of standard .NET events is the type (in this case) `IEvent<Windows.RoutedEventHandler,Windows.RoutedEventArgs>`. As you can see from the documentation, [IEvent implements IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340439.aspx). In other words, in F# every single event already is an `IObservable`.

Answer (score 6):

Joel Mueller is spot on, so just for the record: a direct translation of the C# code would be

```
Observable.FromEvent(
    (fun h -> RoutedEventHandler(fun sender e -> h.Invoke(sender, e))),
    (fun h -> b.Click.AddHandler h),
    (fun h -> b.Click.RemoveHandler h)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at the C# code in Reflector made me realize that 'h' actually gets expanded to 'h.Invoke', which then gets treated as a method group that represents '(s,e) => h.Invoke(s,e)' and thus satisfies the RoutedEventHandler signature.  Once that is clear, it is obvious that you are right on the money with your suggested F# implementation.
I also agree though, that the less verbose conversion suggested by Joel Mueller is to be preferred unless you need to get a hold of the sender directly (e.g. not via args.Source), since it only returns an IObservable of the RoutedEventArgs.